# Entity event subscriptions clean-up

Tags: javascript, typescript, memory, memory-leaks, breeze

I'm using BreezeJS. Suppose we've a custom `EntityBase` class and subscribed to some `entityAspect` events (`propertyChanged`, `validationErrorsChanged`) and/or to events of its collection properties (`arrayChanged`) in its entity initializer method (the sample below is in TypeScript):

```
import { Entity, EntityAspect } from "breeze-client";

export abstract class EntityBase implements Entity {
    public static initializer(entity: EntityBase): void {
        const entityAspect: EntityAspect = entity.entityAspect;

        entityAspect.propertyChanged.subscribe(EntityBase.propertyChangedHandler);
        entityAspect.validationErrorsChanged.subscribe(EntityBase.validationErrorHandler);
    }
}

export class Contact extends EntityBase {
    /// [Initializer]
    public static initializer(entity: EntityBase): void {
        super.initializer(entity);

        (entity as Contact).addresses.arrayChanged.subscribe(Contact.addressesChangedHandler);
    }
    /// </code>

    // Generated code. Do not place code below this line.
    public addresses: Address[];
}

        // Somewhere where MetadataStore is initialized.
        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor("Contact", Contact, Contact.initializer);
```

This means that at some point of time between the entity detaching and before it's garbge-collected, we have to unsubscribe from those events to prevent memory leaks. So we kind of need to have an entity finalizer/destructor.

I don't see any obvious plug-in points into the entity life cycle for this in the Breeze API.

Can somebody give an idea of how to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I understand the question.  But to to make sure let me restate the issue and add some context.  Once an entity is detached it will get garbage collected unless you keep a separate reference to it. This garbage collection will also collect any subscriptions made to each entity's 'entityAspect'.  So the only way that you will see a leak ( after garbage collection) is if you keep a subscription on some object separate from the entity itself ( or it's EntityAspect).  In your case, it's not clear to me if the EntityBase handlers you have defined are static or instance level, but if static then you WILL need to unsubscribe.

To do this the Breeze EntityManager has an [entityChanged event](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html) that may be used like so:

```
var em = new EntityManager( {serviceName: "api/NorthwindIBModel" });
em.entityChanged.subscribe(function(changeArgs) {
    // This code will be executed any time any entity within the entityManager is added, 
    // modified, deleted or detached for any reason. 
    var action = changeArgs.entityAction;
    var entity = changeArgs.entity;
    // unsubscribe here if detaching.
});
```

Does this make sense?